# Solr Querying Child document

Tags: solr

I normally use elasticsearch and I'm new to solr. How can I search zip codes in child documents in some code  like below?  Is it even possible?

```
{
  name: "my Name",
  phone: {
     mobile: "(123) 456 7800", 
     mobile2: "(123) 456 7800"
  },
  Address:{
     Home: {
        address: "123 something way",
        cs: "El Cerrito, CA",
        zip: 99999
     },
     Work: {
        address: "444 Goldriver drive",
        cs: "Cool, CA",
        zip: 88888  
     }
 }
}
```

Comment: there are a couple of solution, you might want to google "block join" -- which allows parent/child relationships. Solr isn't going to be as user-friendly as ES, its going to bubble more lower-level concerns up to you. Its a bit of a power vs ease of use tradeoff.